# Calculate total Reimbursement for same start and end destination

Tags: sql

I have to reimburse the amount to an employee only if the employee start and end destination for the entire journey are the same. I.e If the start point is A and then the destination is B at one leg of the journey and second leg has start point B or C but the destination is B.

Below is an example.

```
Employee Name|Employee ID|From station|To station|Amount
-------------|-----------|------------|----------|---------
    Jon      |    1      |    BLR     |    HYD   | 1000
    Jon      |    1      |    HYD     |    DEL   | 1000
    Russ     |    2      |    BLR     |    DEL   | 1500
    Russ     |    2      |    DEL     |    BLR   | 1500
    Raj      |    3      |    BLR     |    DEL   | 1500
    Raj      |    3      |    DEL     |    HYD   | 1300
    Raj      |    3      |    Hyd     |    JAI   | 1200
```

I only want my SQL query to Return Russ as for Russ start and end destination are same.
.
Can anyone please help me writing the query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no obvious way to determine where the beginning and end of employee journeys without an ordering column.

Comment: As noted below, you're missing a column, which you could call 'journey_leg.'

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, to really answer your question, you need a column that specifies the order of the rows.

A close approximation is that the set of from and to values are the same.  You can do this by counting:

```
select t.*
from (select employeeid, count(distinct fromstation) as num_from,
             count(distinct tostation) as numto,
             count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by employeeid
     ) t join
     t tfrom
     on tfrom.employeeid = t.employeeid join
     t tto
     on tto.employeeid = t.employeeid and
        tto.tostation = tfrom.fromstation
where t.numfrom = t.numto and t.numfrom = t.cnt
group by t.employeeid, t.cnt
having t.cnt = count(*);
```

This is not precise, but it will work for reasonable assumptions about the data -- such as not returning to the same station more than once and continuous journeys.

Comment: I think you'll have to put a dummy aggregate on that `having t.cnt`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a 'journey identifier',because as you add records, you will not be able to tell to which journey a trip belongs to. You also need some ordering of the trips, otherwise how can you know the start and the final destination ?

You can also try to normalize your DB, which should simplify the reasoning around the queries.

I've come up with something like that:

```
create table employee
(
    id   serial primary key,
    name varchar not null
);

create table journey
(
    id       serial primary key,
    employee integer not null references employee (id) on delete cascade
);

create table trip
(
    id           serial primary key,
    journey      integer     not null references journey (id) on delete cascade,
    from_station varchar     not null,
    to_station   varchar     not null,
    trip_date    timestamptz not null,
    amount       real        not null
);
```

Then you can get the employee, journey and amount to reimurse in one go:

```
select e.id           as emp_id,
       e.name         as employee,
       j.id           as journey_id,
       st.trip_date   as trip_start,
       et.trip_date   as trip_end,
       sum(wt.amount) as amount
from employee e
         join journey j on e.id = j.employee
         join trip st on j.id = st.journey
         join trip et on j.id = et.journey
         join trip wt on j.id = wt.journey
where st.from_station = et.to_station
  and st.trip_date = (select min(t.trip_date) from trip t where t.journey = j.id)
  and et.trip_date = (select max(t.trip_date) from trip t where t.journey = j.id)
group by e.id, j.id, e.name, st.trip_date, et.trip_date;
```

Here is a db-fiddle to play with: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tkNtcJqzWpEoixwf5Vr8Qr/0